# Usage of RestTemplate to call ResponseEntity of another RESTful service in Java

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot

@RequestMapping("/viewall")
    public String getAllEmployees(Model model) {

```
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
    Collection<Map> entity = (ArrayList<Map>) restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:8080/employees", Collection.class);

            List<Employee> tempListForEmployee = new ArrayList<>();

    for(Map map : entity) {

        for(Map.Entry entry : map.entrySet()) { // map.entrySet() ..1
            tempMapForEmployee.add((Employee) entry.getValue());
        }

    }

    model.addAttribute("emp", tempMapForEmployee);

    return "viewall";
}
```

Why ..1 is giving error as "Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to Map.Entry" 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Specify type in Map.Entry in inner for loop

Comment: like for(Map.Entry<Key, Employee> entry : map.entrySet()) { // map.entrySet() ..1
            tempMapForEmployee.add((Employee) entry.getValue());
        }

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about your key of map, assuming key is 'String'

Instead of ..

```
for(Map map : entity) {

    for(Map.Entry entry : map.entrySet()) { // map.entrySet() ..1
        tempMapForEmployee.add((Employee) entry.getValue());
    }

}
```

Use below.

```
for(Map /*Mention the map key, value type here <key,value>*/ map: entity) {

    for(Map.Entry<String, Employee>  entry : map.entrySet()) { // map.entrySet() ..1
        tempMapForEmployee.add((Employee) entry.getValue());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The quickest fix would be to let the compiler know about the arguments of `Map`

```
    for (Map<?,?> map : entity) {
        for (Map.Entry<?, ?> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            tempListForEmployee.add((Employee) entry.getValue());
        }
    }
```

But you could consider improving on this code quite a lot, e.g.

```
    for (Map<?,Employee> map : entity) {
        tempListForEmployee.addAll(map.values());
    }
```